# Is it possible to debug a Service Fabric application in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-service-fabric, vscode-debugger

I would like to be able to deploy and debug a Service Fabric app to my local SF Cluster using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a Powershell script to deploy the application from VS Code, but there is no way to attach to a process for debugging. You'd have to use Visual Studio or Rider to do that.